# How to set font size greater than 300 for uilabel in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistoryboard, font-size, uifont

In storyboard the font size for UILabel  can't be increased above 300. How this limit occurs and how can we overcome this limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible from storyboard but can be done from code.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:400];
label.text = @"AI";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use your existing label instead of creating a brand new one in code:

```
label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:400];
```